# A pivot table with page fields must be located above row 3. Current location is A1

Tags: c#, pivot-table, epplus

Got into a problem with EPPlus.

Want to prepare a second pivottable based on the data of the first pivottable (done using CacheDefinition.SourceRange) and cannot add a filter (PageField).
When I run this is breaks on the last line of this code with the error: "A pivot table with page fields must be located above row 3. Currenct location is A1"...
Dont' know what's wrong here.

CODE:

```
var reportFilterNames = new List<string>() { "ProjectName" };
var valueNames = new List<string>() { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };

ExcelWorksheet wsChart = report.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Chart-Projects");
var dataRange = pivotTableProjects.CacheDefinition.SourceRange;
ExcelPivotTable pivotTable = wsChart.PivotTables.Add(wsChart.Cells[1, 1], dataRange, "PivotTableChart");

pivotTable.MultipleFieldFilters = true;
pivotTable.RowGrandTotals = true;
pivotTable.ColumGrandTotals = true;
pivotTable.Compact = true;
pivotTable.CompactData = true;
pivotTable.GridDropZones = false;
pivotTable.Outline = false;
pivotTable.OutlineData = false;
pivotTable.ShowError = true;
pivotTable.ErrorCaption = "[ERROR]";
pivotTable.ShowHeaders = true;
pivotTable.UseAutoFormatting = true;
pivotTable.ApplyWidthHeightFormats = true;
pivotTable.ShowDrill = true;
//pivotTable.FirstDataCol = 2;
pivotTable.RowHeaderCaption = "Projects";

pivotTable.Indent = 0;
pivotTable.DataOnRows = true;

foreach (string reportFilterName in reportFilterNames)
    pivotTable.PageFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields[reportFilterName]);
```

Any advise?

Comment: If it helps someone look into the issue, here is the source for this exception: [EPPlus/EPPlus/Table/PivotTable/ExcelPivotTableFieldCollection.cs](https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/0d53d2f885857f6cdf52ef940baae1024e4b301b/EPPlus/Table/PivotTable/ExcelPivotTableFieldCollection.cs#L207)

Comment: But as expected "A1" is above row 3... isn't it? So...

Comment: I am not experienced in EPPlus, but as my basic eye notices, the condition triggering the exception is `if (_table.Address._fromRow < 3)`, its quite confusing since the exception message is unclear though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all folkz, I figured it out!
Problem was, that there is NO room to add the filter selection...

When I tweaked that line:

```
    ExcelPivotTable pivotTable = wsChart.PivotTables.Add(wsChart.Cells[1, 1], dataRange, "PivotTableChart");
```

To that:

```
    ExcelPivotTable pivotTable = wsChart.PivotTables.Add(wsChart.Cells[3, 1], dataRange, "PivotTableChart");
```

This will give more space before the pivottable and then, the error is gone. 
So be aware to add a higher starting row, if you want to add more than one filter.

Hopefully it could help someone in future to see this post.